# Does my spinner has to extend an Activity

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to put a spinner in my activity. Does my spinner have to be an activity? I am developing for a tablet and i just want the spinner to be an item in the activity. If it doesn't do i still have to use the OnCreate method and setContentView..etc..?

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.app.Activity;


public class GenderSpinner{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adminfieldfrag);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gen_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);    
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override   
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                String select = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
               // your code here
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: If you learned the basics to android, you wouldn't have to ask this.

Comment: well i've read thru both books Hello, Android and Beginning Android Tablet application development on the matter and they both do not state whether it has to be an activity or not. The on for Android tablet doesn't even mention the spinner. I've also consulted the web. Thats why i'm here...to shine some light on the matter. Not to mention if everyone knew everything they needed to know about android would this forum need to exist...just sayin.

Comment: Can only assume that you have read the documentation correctly, obviously you haven't. Either that or you skipped over the fundamentals, which is why, better you learn now then later... Specifically a Activity cannot be a View, so no you wouldn't have your spinner extends an Activity. A view is a visible  display that the user can interact with or see, an Activity manages this, so they do not relate to eachother at all

Comment: An just an fyi but a Spinner is a View because the user interacts with it AND see it. Also a tablet makes no difference, it is android in general tablet or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517) for a simple spinner just follow this,I hope this will help you.

Comment: not really. All the examples i've seen has the spinner as a seperate activity cause its on a mobile phone with small screen. I am developing for a tablet so i just need it to be a dropdown menu on my screen. Appreciate the response though :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use spinner in your android application, you have to use it as a View in your android activity. And for an activity to be a part of your application, you have to override its onCreate() method.

In order to display something on screen while your activity is at the top of the activity task, you must set some view using setContentView(layoutid).

Please keep in mind,Spinner is just a view. So think it in that way.

Comment: I was thinking i had to put the spinner class is a separate class file by itself. Would it make more sense to include it in the main activity class file? Then i wouldn't be getting setContextView as an error?

Comment: Yes, just treat it as one of your view inside your main layout that you set using setContentView() within your main activity. Obviously it would make sense if you do the same.